# Symmetric routing and asymmetric routing plz elaborate

Tags: network, networking, network-core, network-theory, network-measurement

First of all thanks,

Am pretty much confused this both term of routing read blog's and notes but still kinda confused.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Symmetric routing - packet takes one path towards for example google server and turn back on using the same path.

Asymmetric - packet takes one path towards for example google server and return back using different path.

Comment: One practical situation is with stateful firewalls. A firewall sees the socket initiated in one direction and automatically allows the return traffic. But that only works if traffic for that socket goes through the same firewall in both directions.